# configure nginx, namecheap show domain instead of ip

Tags: web, nginx

My nginx config file is basic:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  location / {
    root /var/www/html/;
  }
}
```

In namecheap I have a urldirect forwarding to my ip, 123.45.67.89
When I put 123.45.67.89/img.jpg into the browser, I get the proper image. When I type in example.com/img.jpg, my browser is directed to 123.45.67.89 and I get a 403 forbidden (I have no index.html).

What do I have to do to get my server to display the proper domain. Am I utilizing the incorrect menu within namecheap?

I realize this is an extreme newbie question, but I have struggled with this for a long time; it has kept me from attempting any serious web work and it is the bane of my existence. Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure if this might help (or if this is even necessary), but have you tried adding example.com to hosts file? like `127.0.0.1 example.com` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com www.example.com;

  location / {
  root /var/www/html/;
  }

   location ~* \.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|ico|avi|mp4|m4v|flv) {
   expires max;
    root /var/www/img/
    try_files $uri =404;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the simple config is all you need.

The issues were on the registers' side, or more correctly, on the side of me not knowing the correct option to change.

Where I was using "urldirect forwarding" I should have been using "A (Address)".